# MySQL importing csv file by Data import wizard

Tags: mysql, import, data

I tried importing a CSV file in MySQL via the data import wizard.

My CSV file has 70,000 records but only 61 are imported.

I tried checking the CSV file, recreating the file from source, and changing the location of the CSV file, but nothing works.

I even reinstalled MySQL version 8.0.25.

Please suggest a solution or any other way of importing.

Comment: Are there any errors? Have your looked at the data on line 61/62 ? Is the data different ?

Comment: *but only 61 are imported* This means that 62th rows causes an error. Import using CLI  (LOAD DATA INFILE) and look for error.

Comment: When you say "recreated data from ... where I took it" do you mean there is another MySQL database that has the source data you're migrating?

Answer (score 0):

Try using `mysqldump` command for dumping data from source to destination server.

**Step1** : Take backup from Source server for particular table.

```
mysqldump --single-transaction  --set-gtid-purged=OFF  --force  -h 192.168.XX.XX -u user_name -p --databases database_name --tables table_name --lock-tables=false > mysql_user.sql
```

**Step2** : Restore the backup on Destination.

```
mysql -u user_name -p -h192.168.X.X database_name < mysql_user.sql
```

Comment: The question has nothing to do with migrating data from one db to another.

Comment: He asked to "Please suggest a solution or any other way of importing"

Comment: "Please suggest a solution or any other way of importing" **a csv file**, not a database dump.